# sql statement to delete rows in table 1 according to records in another tale

Tags: sql

I have to tables t1 and t2.
I want to

*delete records in t1, where*

*t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND t1.c2 = t2.c2 AND t1.c3 = t2.c3 AND t2.c4 = "something"*

I thought I could do something like:

```
delete
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
 on 
 (t1.c1 = t2.c1 
  AND t1.c2 = t2.c2 
  AND t1.c3 = t2.c3)
 where t2.c4 = 'something'
```

but, before doing that I'm trying to do

```
select *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
 on 
 (t1.c1 = t2.c1 
  AND t1.c2 = t2.c2 
  AND t1.c3 = t2.c3)
 where t2.c4 = 'something'
```

and it's not returning the records I want to delete.

Any tips on how to fix this query? (to work in oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!!

```
 DELETE  
    FROM    table1 t1
    WHERE EXISTS
      SELECT * 
      from table2 t2
      where  t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND 
            t1.c2 = t2.c2 AND 
            t1.c3 = t2.c3 AND
            t2.c4 = 'something'
```

Answer (score 2):

you are very close!, just add the table name where you want to delete after `DELETE` keyword

```
DELETE  t1   -- <<==== HERE
FROM    table1 t1
        INNER JOIN table2 t2
            ON  t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND 
                t1.c2 = t2.c2 AND 
                t1.c3 = t2.c3
 WHERE  t2.c4 = 'something'
```

Comment: Yes, because otherwise it would would be ambiguous from what table you want to delete. t2 would also work.

Comment: I see, but shouldn't my select statement (second query in my question on top) return the rows that are going to be deleted?

Comment: it's not working.. It's giving me 
Error at Command Line:1 Column:9
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: and I guess it's probably because oracle does not support join for delete statements.. :) 
not sure how to do it though